# Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am having problems compiling my app with Android Studio (0.1.5).
The  app  uses 2 libraries which I have included as follows:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':myapp',':library',':android-ColorPickerPreference'
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':android-ColorPickerPreference')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

When compiling I get this message:

```
  Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':myapp'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Could you help me with this message? Thanks!

Comment: do the library projects declared in settings.gradle all have correctly configured build.gradle files in the project roots? also :library and :android-ColorPickerPreference need to be in directories at the same level in your dir stucture as your settings.gradle file?

Comment: This problem occurred with me when I didn't have a build.gradle file in one of my library projects.  Creating this file made the error go away.

Comment: In my case one of my gradle configuration file is missing.It is not properly push.

Comment: how to create gradle.build file ..i'm also facing same issue?

Answer (score 82):

In my case, after compiling with `gradle tasks --info`, the log was there :

> Evaluating project ':libraries:VolleyLibrary' using empty build
>   file.

So it failed to find build.gradle file of the library. 
Reason is the folder structure.

It was

```
-libraries
--volley
---VolleyLibrary
```

It is supposed to be

```
-libraries
--VolleyLibrary
```

Comment: How did you get it to evaluate ':libraries:VolleyLibrary'?  What does that line look like in your build.gradle file?

Comment: dependencies{ compile ':libraries:VolleyLibrary'}
It should be something like this and nothing more.

Comment: According to your code sample above, :Libraries should be capitalized.

Comment: For some reason, on Ubuntu, `gradlew` is not marked as executable. It was trivial to fix: `chmod +x gradlew`, then `./gradlew tasks --info` in my case revealed the problem with a missing git submodule.

Comment: How do you compile with "gradle tasks --info"?

Comment: `./gradlew tasks --info` this will show the information of all the tasks. I think this would be helpful to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 60):

I forgot to pull all submodules. So my

```
compile project(':something')
```

could not be resolved.

### Solution

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Please explain on which folder should i run this command - project folder or submodule folder

Comment: this one should be accepted answer. misleading error message in most cases means that you forgot to clone submodules

Comment: In my case I hard forgot to remove the submodule from settings.gradle file. So be careful! :D

Answer (score 20):

```
compile fileTree(dir: '//you libraries location//', include: ['android-ColorPickerPreference'])
```

Use above line in your app's **gradle** file instead of

```
compile project(':android-ColorPickerPreference')
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 19):

The following procedure solved my issue:

- Go to your sub-project-module/library-module settings. (press <kbd>F4</kbd> after selecting the   module)
- Right Click on **Add > Android-Gradle**.
- Add build.gradle to your module.
- Add the following script

  ```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
  }
   }


    apply plugin: 'android-library'

  repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  }

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 18
  buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

  defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 10
      targetSdkVersion 18
  }

  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
          java.srcDirs = ['src']
          resources.srcDirs = ['src']
          aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
          renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
          res.srcDirs = ['res']
          assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      }

  }
     }
  ```

  5. add `include ':yourModuleName'` in your settings.gradle

Comment: When I select the library project module settings isn't an option and f4 does nothing.

Comment: @DanielBaughman please clarify your query, but in case you are still unable to find the module settings, you can do 2 things:
1) Go to File > Import Module and follow the steps, Android Studio will automatically add the build.gradle file and also add the dependencies.
2) Manually add the build.grade file write the script in it and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I had done is actually put the folder I was importing into the project - imported the module, and then, in my project properties, referenced the source module I had targeted to be imported as the library instead of the new module folder it created.  I adjusted that reference and it fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

I've also faced with this error - I forgot to create build.gradle script for library project.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another cause - I was trying to include a module in settings.gradle using

```
include ':MyModule'
project(':MyModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../MyModule')
```

Only problem was, I had just imported the module from Eclipse an forgot to move the directory outside my application project, i.e. the path `'../../MyModule'` didn't exist.

Comment: This was more or less my issue as well. I had one too many `../` in the path and it wasn't pointing to the correct place. This is especially hard to track down because Android Studio / Gradle will create the directory if it doesn't exist. Instead of throwing a simple error saying "Nope."

Answer (score 7):

My solution is to simply remove a line from the settings.gradle file, which represents a module that doesn't exist:

```
include ':somesdk'
```

and also remove the corresponding line from the main project's build.gradle:

```
compile project(':somesdk')
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a git submodule problem when getting this error. Try running `gradle tasks --info` for a more detailed problem description. I first used `gradle tasks --debug`, which was not nearly as helpful as `--info`.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to add a library (for example MyLib) to your project, You should follow these steps:

1. Prepare your library as a gradle Android library if your library's type is Eclipse ADT
   For this job it's enough to import it in Android Studio
2. Copy your library folder, in this case MyLib folder, and paste it in your main project folder. It's a good practice to create a new folder in your main project folder and name it Libraries
3. Go to Android Studio and open **Settings.gradle** file, there you should include your library in your main project. For example `include ':MyPrj', 'Libraries:MyLib'`. **Note**: Current directory for this include statement is your main project folder. If you paste your project into a folder you must mention it's address relative to the main project directory. In my case I paste **MyLib** into **Libraries** folder. This **Libraries** name is not a keyword and you can choose other names for it
4. Open your Project Structure page(**File->Project Structure...**) click on modules then click on your main project go to dependencies tab click on `+` then choose **Module dependency** and there is your libraries and you can select them as you want

Hope it help

Comment: to be clear, go to github project `sliding-menu ` https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library and check its structure! There is old format android project `+` build.gradle file!! Thanks, @ABFORCE +1

Comment: This post helped me with importing OpenCV4Android into Android Studio, so I'll vouch for this method.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was using Gradle files that work under Windows but failed on Linux. The `include ':SomeProject'` and `compile project(':SomeProject')` were case sensitive and were not found.

Answer (score 4):

For me folder was missing which was declared under **settings.gradle**.

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks fine at first blush, but some poking around on here found an answer that could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16905808/7944

Even the original answer writer doesn't sound super confident, but it's worth following up on. Also, you didn't say anything about your directory structure and so I'm assuming it's boring default stuff, but can't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

One other potential cause of this precise error: I found this error was resolved by commenting some unused libraries in build.gradle dependencies section.  Make sure these paths and such are all correct.

I'd look real close at your compile project(':android-ColorPickerPreference') entry in the build.gradle - try commenting out the related code and this line in build.gradle and see if that compiles - then go from there resolving the path or library issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and found very simple way to add a library to the project.

1. Create folder "libs" in the root of your project.
2. Copy JAR file into that folder.
3. Go back to Android Studio, locate your JAR file and right click it, choose "Add As Library...", it will ask you only to which module you want to add it, well choose "app".

Now in your "app" module you can use classes from that JAR, it will be able to locate and add "import" declarations automatically and compile just okay. The only issue might be is that it adds dependency with absolute path like:

```
compile files('/home/user/proj/theproj/libs/thelib-1.2.3.jar')
```

in your "app/build.gradle".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by fixing some paths in **settings.gradle** as shown below:

```
include ':project-external-module'

project(':project-external-module').projectDir = file('/project/wrong/path')
```

I was including an external module to my project and had the wrong path for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I manually pasted google-play-services_lib into my project.  Obviously, play-services didn't have a build.gradle file in it.  The solution, I learned, is to put this dependency in my project's **build.gradle** (instead of hard-copying the play-services directory):

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

When i import my library manually i had same issue. I tried to add my library with file > import module and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I received this error when I misspelled the module name of the library (dependency) in `build.gradle` file.

So remember to check if the name of the module is correct.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module-name-of-the-library')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this error when I refereneced a project that was initiliazed via a git submodule.

I ended up finding out that the root `build.gradle` file of the submodule (a java project) did not have the java plugin applied at the root level.

It only had

`apply plugin: 'idea'`

I added the java plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Once I applied the java plugin the 'default not found' message disappeared and the build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

**Also... check if you have the module files inside your project.**

For example, I have an app which uses the Volley module. During my studies on Android development, I accidentally removed the files which were inside the "volley" directory..

```
~/git/Sandbox/android/HelloWorld/volley $ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 ivanleon ivanleon 4096 Jun 16 22:26 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 ivanleon ivanleon 4096 Jun 17 01:51 ../
```

I just cloned the project **(see bellow)** and then, I made the Sync of the project at Android Studio **(Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files)**, and Gradle build finished normally **(Gradle Console: bottom right corner of Android Studio)** ;).

```
~/git/Sandbox/android/HelloWorld/volley $ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
Cloning into 'volley'...
remote: Counting objects: 164, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (164/164)
remote: Total 3222 (delta 307), reused 3222 (delta 307)
Receiving objects: 100% (3222/3222), 1.22 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (307/307), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

~/git/Sandbox/android/AndroidGetJSON $ ls volley
Android.mk      build         build.xml         pom.xml       
proguard-project.txt      src    bintray.gradle  build.gradle
custom_rules.xml  proguard.cfg  rules.gradle          volley.iml
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **build.gradle** for the module/library could be as simple as:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

If your module is just a collection of .java POJO classes.

If it's model / entity classes and you're using annotations and have some dependencies you could add those in:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:4.48'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are compiling imported or copied folder/project as module in libraries folder. This issue was raising when I did not include the `build.gradle` file. when I added the file all went just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out to be an relative symbolic link (to the referenced project) that couldn't be used by grade. (I was referencing a library). Thats a pretty edgy edge-case but maybe it helps someone in the future.

I solved it by putting a absolute symbolic link.

Before `ln -s ../library` after `ln -s /the/full/path/to/the/library`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and it resolved by changing one flag (gradle.ext.set("allowLocalEdits", true)) to false in settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

For me, one of dependent library does not exist in correct path, but the error message does not point THAT library correctly.

For example, what I missed is `:library-3` but the error throws at `:library-1`.

poor gradle.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding Volley library and sync and run the program. if one has pulled and i has volley usage and the error shows as -Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found then follow the step of adding the volley library in your gradle. hope it helps. I cleared my problem this way.