# Configuration with name 'default' not found. Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio app. It has a library dependency (Android-Bootstrap), when I try to sync gradle, it gives me an error:

> Configuration with name 'default' not found.

My structure is:

```
-FTPBackup
   -fotobackup
     -build.gradle
   -Libraries
     -Android-Bootstrap
       -Settings.gradle
       -build.gradle
-Settings.gradle
-Build.gradle
```

The FTPBackup settings.gradle and build.gradle:

```
include ':fotobackup'
include ':libraries:Android-Bootstrap',':Android-Bootstrap'
```

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle inside fotobackup is:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project (':libraries:Android-Bootstrap')
}
```

The library is downloaded from https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap and it has build.gradle, settings etc.

whats wrong?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found)

Answer (score 73):

For one, it doesn't do good to have more than one **settings.gradle** file -- it only looks at the top-level one.

When you get this "Configuration with name 'default' not found" error, it's really confusing, but what it means is that Gradle is looking for a module (or a build.gradle) file someplace, and it's not finding it.  In your case, you have this in your **settings.gradle** file:

```
include ':libraries:Android-Bootstrap',':Android-Bootstrap'
```

which is making Gradle look for a library at **FTPBackup/libraries/Android-Bootstrap**. If you're on a case-sensitive filesystem (and you haven't mistyped **Libraries** in your question when you meant **libraries**), it may not find **FTPBackup/Libraries/Android-Bootstrap** because of the case difference. It's also looking for another library at **FTPBackup/Android-Bootstrap**, and it's definitely not going to find one because that directory isn't there.

This should work:

```
include ':Libraries:Android-Bootstrap'
```

You need the same case-sensitive spec in your `dependencies` block:

```
compile project (':Libraries:Android-Bootstrap')
```

Comment: Ok, now work but is for other cause. Androi-Bootstrap have inside 2 other projects. I copy the project i need to /libraries and now work.Your commen of the duplicate settings.gradle guide me. thanks

Comment: For the readers - The problem could also be coming from GIT and case insensitive file systems (like on most Macs). If you renamed a folder by changing only the case and nothing else - when you commit it hell will break loose. The change will not be propagated to your colleagues or the build server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git

Comment: Other possible cause: When importing a module, specifically select the "settings.gradle" of the root project, not the root project folder. In my case, Android Studio was confused because it found multiple settings.gradle files (as a result of submodules). After selecting the settings.gradle as import target, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 25):

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: ['Android-Bootstrap'])
```

Use above line in your app's gradle file instead of

```
compile project (':libraries:Android-Bootstrap')
```

Comment: had to do this for a subproject when the parent was converted into a library project.

Answer (score 17):

In my setting.gradle, I included a module that does not exist. Once I removed it, it started working. This could be another way to fix this issue

Comment: worked for me :) , i added volley as a module, but didn't include it in git, so when i cloned the project again it gave me that error because volley folder wasn't there, thanks a lot <3 :D

Answer (score 8):

If you're getting this error with react native, it may be due to a link to an NPM package that you removed (as it was in my case). After removing references to it in the settings.gradle and build.gradle files, I cleaned and rebuilt and it's as good as new :)

Comment: I had the same issue. I removed an NPM package and got this error. I removed the references in `settings.gradle`, `build.gradle` and also `src/main/java/[your appname]/MainApplication.java`. To clean you can use `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 3):

Just a note on this question:

I had this exact error in my React Native app when trying to build to android. All you should have to do is `$ npm i`.

Comment: This fixed my problem as well. The issue was that I had dependencies listed in my `package.json` that weren't installed.

Answer (score 2):

**Case matters**
I manually added a submodule `:k3b-geohelper`
 to the 
`settings.gradle` file

```
 include ':app', ':k3b-geohelper'
```

and everthing works fine on my mswindows build system

When i pushed the update to github the [fdroid build system](http://fdroid.org) failed with

```
  Cannot evaluate module k3b-geohelper : Configuration with name 'default' not found
```

The final solution was that the submodule folder was named `k3b-geoHelper` not `k3b-geohelper`.

Under MSWindows case doesn-t matter but on linux system it does

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Jenkins.  The cause: I had renamed a module `module` to `Module`.  I found out that git had gotten confused somehow and kept both `module` and `Module` directories, with the contents spread between both folders.  The `build.gradle` was kept in `module` but the module's name was `Module` so it was unable to find the default configuration.

I fixed it by backing up the contents of `Module`, manually deleting `module` folder from the repo and restoring + pushing the lost files.

Answer (score 1):

The message is a known [Gradle bug](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/error-reporting-configuration-with-name-default-not-found/13487). The reason of your error is that some of your `gradle.build` files has no `apply plugin: 'java'` in it. And due to the bug Gradle doesn't say you, where is the problem.

But you can easily overcome it. Simply put `apply plugin: 'java'` in every your 'gradle.build'

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and the problem was that the libraries were missing in some of the following files.

settings.gradle, app/build.gradle, package.json, MainApplication.java

Suppose the library is react-native-vector-icons then it should be mentioned in following files;

### In app/build.gradle file under dependencies section add:

compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')

### In settings.gradle file under android folder, add the following:

include ':react-native-vector-icons' project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')

### In MainApplication.java, add the following:

Import the dependency: import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

and then add: new VectorIconsPackage() in getPackages() method.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem, I was fixed it by generating gradle project and then adding lib project to android studio

First, See build.gradle file is present in project root directory

if not then, Create gradle project,

1. export your required lib project from eclipse then (File->Export->Android->generate Gradle build file
2. Click on Next->Next->Select your lib project from project listing->Next->Next->Finish
3. See build.gradle file present in your project root directory
4. Move this project to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Your module name must be camelCase eg. pdfLib. I had same issue because I my module name was 'PdfLib' and after renaming it to 'pdfLib'. It worked. 
The issue was not in my device but in jenkins server. So, check and see if you have such modulenames

Answer (score 0):

Step.1
`$ git submodule update`

Step.2
`To be commented out the dependences of classpass`

Comment: What? This isn't relevant to the question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off running the command in the console to get a better idea on what is wrong with the settings. In my case, when I ran `gradlew check` it actually tells me which referenced project was missing.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':test'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':testRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :lib-blah.
 Required by:
     project :
  > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :lib-blah: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

The annoying thing was that, it would not show any meaningful error message during the import failure. And if I commented out all the project references, sure it let me import it, but then once I uncomment it out, it would only print that ambiguous message and not tell you what is wrong.