# Android Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I try to add mopub-sdk into my project imported from eclipse to AndroidStudio.
I created folder in my root folder of project, then i add into settings.gradle line: "include ':mopub-sdk' then clicked "Sync now" then i open "Project structure" and add Dependencies to my project and finally i got this error:

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Help please, i try to make this work all day...
I read all subjects about how make this works but nothing helped me...

setting.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':mopub-sdk'
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.brysp.fiszki.angielski"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/MMSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/nmdp_speech_kit.jar')
    compile project(':mopub-sdk')
}
```

Comment: Post `build.gradle`.

Comment: I also try to do this with project fully maked in Android Studio and there was no issues worked perfectly. But in this project i dont know why not....

Comment: Check out this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio.

Comment: So where i have to add this:
    git submodule init
    git submodule update

Comment: I am not sure, that is like I left a link in a comment. If I were you, Id manually set those projects up in Android Studio and not "import them".

Comment: I am not import those mopup-sdk projects. I do exacly what one man wrote in topic which you share to us.

Comment: What is mopup sdks? The link I posted has a few things you can try to resolve your issue.

Comment: It is advertising sdk: mopub.com. I tried evrything of this link

Comment: I am not sure what is in the source of the library. May I ask why you are using mopub.com vs admob?

Comment: Banned on AdMob my roommate was clicking on my phone i "my" ads...

Comment: Old trick and a bad one. Time for a new Google account.

Comment: You really think i want pay another 30 USD to open Google Play accout?

Comment: Last time I checked it was $25. Do you have any apps on Google Play?

Comment: Alright, I see your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

check your **`module`** build.gradle file, make sure your **module**`s build.gradle is under mopub-sdk.

Comment: Are you asking or telling?