# Gradle 'MyTestingApp' project refresh failed Error

Tags: java, android

**I read the answers on this topic, but I do not know why does not work, please help**

*I need add BoltsFramework to my to my project in Android Studio*

***Download*** BoltsFramework. Unzipped this.

***Create*** directory ***libraries*** in my Module(*app*) and copy Unzip BoltsFramework here

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:Bolts-Android-master'
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testing.all.apps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-annotations.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile project('libraries:Bolts-Android-master')
}
```

I get an error:
**Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

What's wrong ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio)

Comment: i read this, and did the same, What's wrong ?