# configuration with name 'default' not found Android Studio Trakt.TV Traktoid

Tags: gradle

I am getting this error

Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found

My build.gradle for app is :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to     all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And my App build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.florianmski.tracktoid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
compile project(':trakt-java-git')
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'

apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.0'
compile 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.0'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this error.

I am trying to build this on Android Studio and tried the other answers :

[Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found)

[Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio)

But these did not help much. So therefore posting again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Go to files and click invalidate Cashes / restart 
see does it work