# unable to fix the project ,gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle

`enter code here`unable to fix the project , new to android studio , need help fixing gradle my gradle file ,happening when i import projects from eclipse, exporting done fine

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

and the error i am getting is

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

changed code
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
 buildscript {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                }
                dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
                }
            }
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.package.name"
                    minSdkVersion 11
                    targetSdkVersion 23
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
            }
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
                compile project(':ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies')
            }

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.package.name"
                    minSdkVersion 11
                    targetSdkVersion 23
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }

                sourceSets {
                    main {
                        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                        java.srcDirs = ['src']
                        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                        res.srcDirs = ['res']
                        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                    }

                    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
                    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

                    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
                    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
                    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
                    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
                    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
                    // by a similar customization.
                    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
                    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
                }

            }
```

Comment: this is usually a project settings.gradle error - most likely gradle can't find one of the dependencies there or a dependency in build.gradle because the settings is missing the proper reference to it. Post settings.gradle

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Add the `defaultConfig` into the android block

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 :** The android part of your gradle file should be inside the applications build.gradle not in the projects root gradle

**There are two gradle files**

**Here is a sample Root Project Gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Sample Module Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: tried the code,         respone            Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'defaultConfig()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Wafi_Smt_24_Nov_15' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: added sample gradle for your reference

Comment: can u post both of your gradle files..?

Comment: Canary 4 was known to introduce some bugs for Instant Apps development.
Please see whether Canary 5 fixes the problems you've been experiencing.