# Configuration with name 'default' not found error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to test to reference without copying a library Project. So I created two projects one is **ProjectA** and one is **LibraryA**. Both projects are located inside the **\StudioProjects** folder. I am trying to reference **LibraryA** from **ProjectA** and I get the error at the title.

Here is **settings.gradle** from **ProjectA**

```
include ':app'
include ':LibraryA'
project(':LibraryA').projectDir = new File('../LibraryA')
```

Here is dependincies from app **build.gradle** of **ProjectA**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':LibraryA')
}
```

I am using **Android Studio 1.5.1**

If I remove    `compile project(':LibraryA')` from dependencies it builds normally, however then I can't referance classes from LibraryA inside ProjectA.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio

Comment: I can't try that because my objective is to reference a library without copying it.

Comment: project(':LibraryA').projectDir = new File('../LibraryA'). In this path you have to refer the module inside the LibraryA project, not the root folder of this project,

Comment: LibraryA is a Project and there is no module inside. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Dgkiusm.png) that shows the inside of LibraryA folder.

Comment: The app folder is a module inside LibraryA. Check the answer below.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you for your answer, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `settings.gradle` (ProjectA) you are referring the wrong folder.

```
include ':LibraryA'
project(':LibraryA').projectDir = new File('../LibraryA')
```

Checking your image, the `LibraryA` folder is a **root** folder.
Gradle is searching for a "module" build.gradle while in this folder there is a top-level file configuration.

**You have to refer to the module inside the LibraryA**

```
project(':LibraryA').projectDir = new File('../LibraryA/app')
```

Of course you have to pay attention if some tasks or variable are defined in the top-level file (LibraryA). In this case you have to clone them inside your top-level file (ProjectA)

Answer (score 0):

One of your projects does not have a valid gradle file. If your library is not a gradle project convert it to gradle project.

If you add your library as a module and select "gradle" when you are importing i think you'll solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I just do not understand what you want to do. But try changing the following line:

```
project(':LibraryA').projectDir = new File('../ProjectA')
```

Comment: What part you do not understand, and change that line with what?