# How to fix dependency issues in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android

I just clones an android project from my local repo and I have trouble to 'build' it. Maybe it missed some external library, but I do not know.

Upon starting a grade build I get the following message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I tried to check the 'Manifest' file, but I can't find it.  I am completely lost...

I am pretty sure this is a configuration error, therefore all the config files I can find here:

`build.gradle (project)`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle (app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.impyiablue.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':LibraryModule')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`cradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Wed Sep 07 20:03:05 CEST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

`settings.gradle:`

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:volley'
include ':LibraryModule'
project(':LibraryModule').projectDir = new File('/Users/adietz/AndroidStudioProjects/LIBS')
```

`local.properties:`

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Sun Oct 15 11:07:25 CEST 2017
sdk.dir=/Users/adietz/Library/Android/sdk
```

The output of `./gradlew build` (from inside the project folder) is the following:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod (file:/Users/adietz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-base-services-2.14.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.217 secs
```

Comment: Seems you use volley as a sub-module in your git repository. Did you try `git submodule --init update` after cloning the repo?

Comment: @Henry: Where to issue that command? And should 'volley' go into some external folder, or to a folder inside 'MyApp' (under 'MyApp/libraries/volley')?

Comment: This command is issued in the command line in the root directory of your project. volley would then be checked out to where it previously was (the location is stored in the git repo). Most likely to `/Users/alex/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/libraries/volley`

Comment: Command seems to be incorrect. I get the list of available option listed.

Comment: sorry, try `git submodule update --init`

Comment: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'libraries/volley' in .gitmodules

Comment: Ok, then it wasn't a submodule. Maybe you cloned it there directly?

Comment: I do not know. In the setup of the different computer I have used this 'volley' library, but I have no idea how I set it up originally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156765/discussion-between-alex-and-henry).

Comment: Currently, I did a 'git clone' of volley and put it in a folder

Comment: I am afraid, I can't help because I know even less about your project.

Comment: Ok great. So I have to wait two days to offer a bounty someone can solve my problem? I just want to 'copy' the project onto a different computer...

Comment: @Alex [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Configuration+with+name+'default'+not+found.) is your friend.

Comment: LOL google is my friend. You think I dod not try google? You really think so? When you get an error message that is extremely unspecific, how to find something useful????

Comment: """Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."""

Comment: Not helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found

Comment: Not helping:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio

Comment: @Alex Sorry, we can't help you with the information you've provided. Please elaborate on the issue. Show us your gradle files, directory structure, etc.

Comment: @Alex In a terminal try `./gradlew build`. What's the output?

Comment: No java yet installed. Also, please see updated question with all the billions of config files....

Comment: Check out `libraries/volley` directory, is there something?

Comment: Yes, I did a 'git clone' of the `volley`
 repo in an folder outside of the project, and then copied all files, folders and subfolders into `libraries/volley`.

Comment: @Alex In root of your project, do `/gradlew build`. What does happen?

Comment: I need to wait until java is installed.....

Comment: (Output: `No Java runtime present, requesting install.`)

Comment: @Alex Without Java how it's supposed to build an Android project or even run your Android Studio?

Comment: I have no idea, but it worked fine on some other project (I created from scratch). Its a Mac, maybe this is the reason (as Macs cannot be used straightforward)

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.159 secs

Comment: (without preceding warnings)

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: Output see above

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution seems to be a change in the file `build.gradle` (for Module:app). If you replace this line

```
compile project(path: ':LibraryModule')
```

with this line:

```
compile project(':libraries:volley')
```

and do 'Clean Project again', different things might happen:

- AndroidStudio start to download stuff
- Other `gradle` files appear mysteriously in your `Gradle Scripts` folder
- Other errors appear (which you can google and actually find some helpful answers)

But it might fix the actual problem...