# How to include GitHut library in my project (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am trying to add this [library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) to my project because I want to change something in a class there. That is why I adding it as a dependencies in my gradile setting is not enough.

I know that in the library it says "If you want use this library, you only have to download MaterialDesign project, import it into your workspace and add the project as a library in your android project settings.". But what does that mean, should I copy all files and put them in my libs folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#how-to-use):

> If you want use this library, you only have to download MaterialDesign project, import it into your workspace and add the project as a library in your android project settings.

Step #1: Download the project, whether via the ZIP file that GitHub gives you or by using `git` to clone the repository

Step #2: Move the `MaterialDesign/` directory into your project directory, as a peer of your existing `app/` module

Step #3: Modify your `settings.gradle` in your project directory to include `:MaterialDesign` in the list of modules to build

Step #4: In your `app` module's `build.gradle` file, add `compile project(':MaterialDesign')` to your `dependencies`

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I did the first and second step, but now I don't know how to add the :MaterialDesign in my Gradile exactly. Is it the Gradile Module file or the Project one ?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev: `settings.gradle` is a text file. You can open it in Android Studio or your favorite text editor. Most likely, it will have a single line, `include ':app'`. Edit it to be `include ':app', ':MaterialDesign'`. Save the modified file. And you are done with Step #3.

Comment: Did that. Now When I try to Sync gradle in Step 4 it says "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found." 

This is how my dependencies look like :

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile project(':MaterialDesign')
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
}

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev: One thing you need to do for certain is get rid of the `compile` line for the copy of that `MaterialDesign` library you are pulling in via the AAR. You cannot have two copies of the same library. Beyond that, perhaps there is something off in your directory structure and `settings.gradle`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22547615/115145

Comment: I followed these steps @CommonsWare mentioned and getting the error
Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libs:recognito.

I am trying to include the lib - https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito