# Importing project from bitbucket , Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new project from Version Control using Git repository
during build process

Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

How to solve this error .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I's Gradle configuration error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio) you can find a suggestion to solve the issue.