# Cannot evaluate module libs:configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

Good morning every body ,Please i have an error at my android application when i try to import file.jar .. I really tried a lot of solution but the error is the same.
Can u help me  please to solve the problem  ! thank you

Comment: Check This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio) that may help you

Comment: thank you  but the error is present again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your library folder in your root location of your project and copy all the library files there. For ex YourProject/yourlibrary then sync it and after that you need to mention that library in settings.gradle e.g include ':yourlibrary' one more thing you need to do is to add this line in build.gradle(Module app)

compile files('libs/yourlibrary')

here is the second way to do this just Go->File in android studio after that find project structure then click on Dependencies -> click on green "+" icon then click on File Dependencies select your required file from your libs or library folder and click ok.

Comment: @OumaymaJaziri if that answer work for you please accept it thanks.