# Configuration with name 'default' not found gradle sync failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

I downloaded OSMonitor app source code from https://github.com/eolwral/OSMonitor
But while syncing gradle it failed with this  log

```
2018-07-29 00:01:40,538 [ thread 19]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Configuration with name 'default' not found. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,539 [ thread 19]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (586ms) 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,545 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,545 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\OSMonitor-master' OSMonitor-master 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,647 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,662 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,662 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,662 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,663 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-07-29 00:01:40,664 [ thread 19]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,678 [J pool 0/7]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [] using cp:  
2018-07-29 00:05:26,687 [J pool 0/7]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,711 [J pool 0/7]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinInitScript] using cp: C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1\lib\gradle-core-2.14.1.jar 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,726 [J pool 0/7]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,727 [J pool 0/7]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinSettingsScript] using cp: C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1\lib\gradle-core-2.14.1.jar 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,730 [J pool 0/7]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,731 [J pool 0/7]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript] using cp: C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1\lib\gradle-core-2.14.1.jar 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,734 [J pool 0/7]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-07-29 00:05:26,735 [J pool 0/7]   INFO -       ScriptTemplatesProviders - [kts] loading script definitions [org.gradle.script.lang.kotlin.KotlinBuildScript] using cp: C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1\lib\gradle-core-2.14.1.jar 
2018-07-29 00:05:38,612 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

the log looks like this

anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: (1) Questions should be self-contained. Try to make a [mcve] instead of linking to an external library. (2) Please format your (log, ...) as code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: [please try to search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio)