# Default not Found android

Tags: gradle, build

I am trying to import a project that sent to me and this error is shown to me after importing , "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)" .

Comment: Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Dude - what did you see when you consulted the IDE log for more details?  For that matter, what *IS* your IDE?  Android Studio?  What version?  What platform?  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/).

Comment: android studio ,

Comment: this some of what inside log file :

Comment: 2018-09-27 07:21:53,933 [ thread 63]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: there is volley library added in the project , i don't know if the error from it or not ??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before continuing, could you please spend a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly?