# Disable configure on demand in Android Studio v 0.5.7

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In the most recent update of Android Studio (v 0.5.7), the option "configure-on-demand" is used by default for gradle builds. This is causing a problem in my current project build. When I try to sync my project with gradle files in Android Studio, I get the following error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':PROJECT_NAME'.
>   Configuration with name 'default' not found.

However everything works fine when I build using command line without the "configure-on-demand" flag.

I tried disabling it by putting "org.gradle.configureondemand=false" in my gradle.properties but it seems that Android Studio doesn't respect this. I still get the same error and the gradle logs show:

> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature

Is there a way to disable this in Android Studio ?

Comment: What are you doing in your build files that it's necessary to disable configure on demand?

Comment: @ScottBarta
I have the following top level directories:

**project/module, base**
and project:module is a dependency for base. The issue goes away if I remove this dependency.

Comment: I don't understand that explanation at all. "Configuration with name 'default' not found" is due to an error in your build files, where you've pointed it at a module that doesn't actually exist. Disabling configure on demand almost certainly isn't the right solution.

Comment: do you really get an "error" regarding ```Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.```? I don't see this but I can confirm that there is somewhat a "warning" in front of each build. But back to you problem: is it answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489 ?

Comment: answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991988/android-studio-0-5-9-2-annoying-gradle-warnings

Answer (score 12):

For Android Studio 1.5.1 - 3.1.3: Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and turn off "Configure on demand".