# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found. Need help adding a library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm attempting to add the ZBarScannerLibrary to my project.

I've added the ZBarScannerLibrary to my app/libraries/ directory.

When I added this to settings.gradle and refreshed- it worked fine:

```
include ':app:libraries:ZBarScannerLibrary'
```

However, when I add this to my build.gradle, I'm getting the error: Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

```
compile project('libraries:ZBarScannerLibrary')
```

I'm following this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TForBjArUNg AND have already checked out this stack overflow question- which hasn't help me: [Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found)

[image]