# Installing UrbanAirship / Phonegap Gradle Issue

Tags: android, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am attempting to get UrbanAirship working with a phonegap app on android. I have the plugin working dandy on iOS but when attempting on Android I get `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.` whenever I try and run the app. I am not very familiar with android but what I do know is that if I uninstall the UrbanAirship plugin everything will boot up fine / run on a phone and in emulator. Assuming this is something easy that my inexperience on Android is causing. Anyone have an idea on where to start? Thanks!

```
Gradle 'android' project refresh failed
  Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Seems like it is likely related to the gradle.build file or lack therof but adding them still results in error. Below I have added a copy of the build.gradle file from the root of my project as well as a screen grab of the structure / files in the directories added by urbans phonegap plugin.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + getVersionCodeFromManifest() + "0")
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    if (multiarch || System.env.BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

def getVersionCodeFromManifest() {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}
```

Screenshot of directory = http://mrtr.co/image/163R0o0d2f18

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found)

Comment: You can use.. https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push plugin. It works with android as well as ios both. thanks