# how can i add poi jar file to android studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, jar, gradle, apache-poi

I'm working on android studio 1.0.1 and am unable to add `poi.jar` file to the project correctly.

I added `poi-3.9.jar` to app/libs file and synchronised the project, however running the project gives this error:

```
failed to complete gradle execution
```

Comment: Making shorter sentences and minor formatting can clarify the meaning of your question. Any error message should be highlighted, or at least very visible at first glance as it is the better indicator of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edited answer, gradle change it.. again..

go to:
file > project structure > click app in the list on left

Click Dependencies tab on top > click green plus > click File dependencies > find your library, should be in libs folder, if not add it in system exploler > Click ok, apply, ok

Rebuild gradle, if you get error, change `build.gradle` in your library:
`compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` to match with your app `build.gradle`

Comment: thnks.. but again i had an error with saying "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? ("Build" tab on top)

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found

Comment: I found the solution... go to:app > src then make new directory as wish.Say it as libs.  Then on the libs folder right click and paste the jar file.then on the jar file right click and then add as library.  Then do above steps as Mij said. But on dependencies click module dependencies