# Adding library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android studio ,i added a library after research ,library is added but after lot of work showing gradle sync is failed  .Now fed up with stuff so i am posting my build.gradle files of library module ,app module and main project. please help me out i want to know library is added perfectly or not.

1. build.gradle of Library

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
     compileSdkVersion 17
     buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 5
       targetSdkVersion 17
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
       }
     }
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
     compile project (':androidHorizontalListView')
   }
   ```
2. build.gradle of app moudle

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.pc2.horizontalscroll"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
     }
   }

   dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
   }
   ```

3 .build.gradle of whole project

```
apply plugin:'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':app')
    compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')

}
```

ERROR LOG

```
2015-04-28 12:00:21,927 [1780546]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Failed to notify project evaluation listener. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Comment: `compile project(':` means that the argument has to me in the same directory of your project. Do you have a module called  `androidHorizontalListView` ?

Comment: Do you try to add .ar library to project? Yes?

Comment: Take a look here, it's explained very easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio?rq=1

Comment: Why library apply plugin: 'com.android.application' change it as apply plugin: 'com.android.library'.show me the gradle sync is failed error log.?

Comment: @Blackbelt dn't know but  i added library as file>import module and then through project structure. Also editing my structure.

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/ also update the sdk versions of library like app's gradle.

Comment: @AnoopM edited error log

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project after following all these instructions.give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found

Comment: @AnoopM thnx plugin was also a mistake. I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it ..
By mistake i put this line
 compile project (':androidHorizontalListView') 
in build.gradle of library project ,after removing this line my code working perfectly.Also as per comments and suggestion change com.android.library
instead of com.android.applicatiion.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should setup your library with the appropriate plugin:

```
com.android.library
```

instead of

```
com.android.application
```

Second step would be also to setup the settings.gradle file in the project root containing all sub projects to get the references working: 
It should contain:

```
include: ':app',':androidHorizontalListView'
```

Please try again to compile the project.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.I changed accordingly .It helped me .

Answer (score 0):

There is an Easy way to do it select file from left of Android Studio 
then select New Module-->Import Existing Project-->Browse the location of your library-->finish

Also add compile project(':your library') in apps build.gradle that's all.