# Configuration with name default not found while importing

Tags: android, git

When I import the following project in studio it gives the error:  **Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-trackercapture

Please tell me what things are missing.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found) answer??

Answer (score 0):

Please check git global username and email in your local machine using following commands -

```
git config --global user.name 
git config --global user.email
```

most probably user email is not same as your github account email. Please update git global email using following command.

> git config --global user.email "Your Email"

Also, you should change git global name to your name using

> git config --global user.name "Your Name"