# Error when include Gradle module

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to include my Android library `androidevents` in my app:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':androidevents'

project(':androidevents').projectDir = new File('path/to/my/library')
```

**build.gradle**

```
...    

dependencies {
    ....
    compile project(':androidevents')
}
```

When I build the project, I get this error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Solved! `androidevents` project dir path was wrong. I had to put the path to the concrete module and I was puting the project root.