# Getting " Gradle sync failed " on Xabber import

Tags: android, android-studio, xmpp, android-gradle-plugin, ejabberd

I was importing the [xabber](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android) demo from github into my android studio . and is shows me error -

```
Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I tried to change the outer gradle and this was of no use i am still getting the same error on syncing my gradle. My outer gradle is -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options      
common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

and settings.gradle is

```
include ':xabber'
include ':xabber:otr4j'
include ':xabber:MemorizingTrustManager'
include ':xabber:emojicon'
```

I have also tried using tips from [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found) but no luck.

Do any one have suggestion or faced same situation and resolved , please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error in multiprojects Gradle setup when some project configuration in unavailable. Gradle trying to load configuration for each project lister in `settings.gradle` and failed on some of them. Try to fetch subprojects with git command: `git submodule update --init --recursive` or if you just download an archive - check `xabber/otr4j`, `xabber/MemorizingTrustManager` and `xabber/emojicon` directories to have `build.gradle` for each.