# Android Studio Gradle project refresh failed:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I want to import library `wheel` to my project. What I have done:

```
1. I imported library wheel to Android Studio in order to have build.gradle in it.
2. I created new folder in my project called libraries and put wheel library to it.
3. I put this code to my settings.gradle: include ':app:libraries:wheel'
4. I put this code to build.gradle: compile project('libraries:wheel');
5. I tried to sync gradle but it failed
```

That's how my project's structure looks like:

[image]

my build.gradle here:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    buildTypes {
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project('libraries:wheel');

}
```

my settings gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:wheel'
```

My failure message:

```
Gradle 'LiteTap' project refresh failed:
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: why didn't you post the failure log messages?

Comment: I think the problem occurs in LiteTap project's setting.gradle which is in lowermost of the project structure. You should also publish that file configuration and check some duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905214/problems-trying-to-create-gradle-build/16905808#16905808
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743582/error-configuration-with-name-default-not-found-in-android-studio

Comment: I have read this before but nothing really helped...I'm trying to do what people have suggested but nothing works... Do you mean file configuration is that code in settings.gradle? Here it is: 
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:wheel'

Comment: In my case, it had to do with having the filesystem configured as case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Try command `gradlew tasks --info` in terminal,

you may see "Evaluating project ':libraries:wheel' using empty build file."

maybe its because `wheel` is not an android studio project, AS didn't find `build.gradle` file

### I fix this problem by import the library with android studio rather than direct copy it the `YOURPRO\libraries`.

[How to use a library project in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377591/how-to-use-a-library-project-in-android-studio)
And it works.

Note that it will be more tidy if your create a `libraries` folder and drag

`wheel` file after your import. Remember to add

`include:libraries:pullToRefreshListView` in your `settings.gradle` file

Comment: The command "gradlew tasks --info" save my a lot of time to find which folder is missing within a big project. :)

Answer (score 1):

**compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: ['wheel'])**

Use this in app's gradle file in dependencies instead of

**compile project('libraries:wheel')**

Answer (score 0):

Add your library folder in your root location of your project and copy all the library files there. For ex YourProject/library then sync it and rest things seems OK to me.

Too check [Configuration with name 'default' not found. Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547364/configuration-with-name-default-not-found-android-studio) and [Android Studio Gradle Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found).