# Configuration with name 'default' not found - HoloGraphLibrary

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I'm trying to install HoloGraphLibrary in my android project. But I get this message everytime I sync gradle:

```
Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

### Here is my Android Menu With the libraries folder:

```
-app
  -build
  -libraries
     -HoloGraphLibrary
        -.settings
        -res
        -src
        AndroidManifest.xml
        build.gradle
        HoloGraphLibrary.iml
        HoloGraphLibrary-HoloGraphLibrary.iml
        LICENSE.txt
        NOTICE.txt
        proguard-project.txt
        project.proprieties
  -libs
  -src
  build.gradle
  app.iml
  .gitignore
  proguard-rules.pro
```

### Here is the build.gradle of my app:

[image: build.gradle]

### And here are the settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:HoloGraphLibrary'
```

### I give you the build.gradle of the HoloGraphLibrary to see:

[image: HoloGraphLibrary build.gradle]

So here I am, stuck with this error, reading all the other posts about this error, all saying to look if there is a build.gradle into the folder of the library which is ok here. Others say that there's a line in the code but which one, I don't know... So I'm here because it's a school project and I need to do some graphics with this library. So if somebody knows how to resolve it, thanks.

I know there are other similar posts. I've already tried to apply the given solutions, but none of them are working for me, which is why I'm posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this use android studio to import module,since the library maybe not an AS project.
take a look at this question.[Android Studio Gradle project refresh failed:Configuration with name 'default' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845009/android-studio-gradle-project-refresh-failedconfiguration-with-name-default-n/28127839#28127839)