# Failed to notify project evaluation listener error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been working on a project for months without issues. Just today re-opened the project in Android Studio and started getting the error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234561/build-gradle-and-project-libs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905214/problems-trying-to-create-gradle-build/16905808), without success.

I also cleaned cache, rebuilt project, restarted my pc, uninstalled and reinstalled Android Support and Google libraries in SDK, and tried with Invalidate Cache and restart. None of these things worked.

And I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1, just in case.

I hope someone could help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

**LOG:**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.common.base.Objects.hashCode(Objects.java:78)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.LibraryDependencyImpl.hashCode(LibraryDependencyImpl.java:145)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap.put(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:192)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractListMultimap.put(AbstractListMultimap.java:100)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap.put(ArrayListMultimap.java:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:807)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:855)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:855)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.addDependency(DependencyManager.java:855)

2016-05-29 15:34:00,668 [ 193987]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Failed to notify project evaluation listener. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:457)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:373)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)

2016-05-29 15:34:00,683 [ 194002]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-05-29 15:34:00,683 [ 194002]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-05-29 15:34:00,683 [ 194002]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'IconShowcase' failed: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-05-29 15:34:00,902 [ 194221]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-29 15:34:00,969 [ 194288]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-29 15:34:01,016 [ 194335]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-29 15:34:01,016 [ 194335]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

[image: Project Structure]

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jahirfiquitiva.apps.iconshowcase.sample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
        generatedDensities = []
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res',
                    'src/main/res/drawable',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/dashboard',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/designer',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/icon_pack',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/launchers_icons',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/widgets',
                    'src/main/res/values',
                    'src/main/res/values/icon_pack',
                    'src/main/res/values/configuration'
            ]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        themeMode {} //themeMode for testing
        standard {} //standard testing without themeMode stuff
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

**library build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
        generatedDensities = []
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res',
                    'src/main/res/drawable',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/dashboard',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/designer',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/icon_pack',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/launchers_icons',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/splash_screens',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/widgets',
                    'src/main/res/layout',
                    'src/main/res/layout/activities',
                    'src/main/res/layout/extras',
                    'src/main/res/layout/items',
                    'src/main/res/layout/sections',
                    'src/main/res/layout/widgets',
                    'src/main/res/values/icon_pack',
                    'src/main/res/values/configuration',
                    'src/main/res/values/texts'
            ]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        aaptOptions {
            noCompress 'zip', 'komp', 'klwp', 'kwgt', 'klck', 'kwch'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0'

    //Material Dialogs
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Material Drawer
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'

    //Glide Library - Image Loading Lib
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0-SNAPSHOT'

    //Sectioned RecyclerView
    compile('com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.1.0'

    //Muzei API
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile 'com.google.android.apps.muzei:muzei-api:2.+'

    //Circular Image View
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'

    //RecyclerView Fast Scroller
    compile 'com.github.pluscubed:recycler-fast-scroll:0.3.1@aar'

    //Donations Lib
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:donations:2.4'

    //License Checker Lib
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:0.0.2'

    //Required for better Zooper setup
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

    //Required for Kustom support.
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile 'org.bitbucket.frankmonza:kustomapi:+'

}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the MaterialDialogs lib version to

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9@aar') { transitive = true }
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem when I moved to a higher level of gradle. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665772/3173397). Try changing the gradle level
In my case, this version helped

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

and this gradele version throws mistakes

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Just do not forget to change distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded an old repository from GitHub and tried to update some versions. Then got this error. After I reverted back

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1-all.zip
```

as @Kamila suggested, the error disappeared.