# Android Studio - Failed to notify project evaluation listener error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Following is the build.gradle code in Android Studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sg.blahblah"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
        xmlReport true
        htmlReport true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:+'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2'
}
```

I am getting the below error:
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

Can anyone please help?

Following is the Instant Run screenshot
[image]

Comment: What is your android studio version??

Comment: Have yo try my answer its work or not ? And AndroidStudio version?

Comment: Android Studio version is 2.3

Comment: I am not able to uncheck Enable Instant Run. I have added the screenshot

Comment: Gradle version?

Comment: Gradle Version is 4.0

Comment: Restart you android studio and check again if it doesn't work then update AndroidStudio 2.3

Comment: I get very sad when there are this many different 'solutions' for a problem. More sad because none of them work for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I am facing same error before a week I solve by disabling the `Instant Run`

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
> uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Hope it works.

**Note** This answer works on below Android Studio 3

Comment: I am trying gradle build from CMD and resulted the above error, @colibrow's answer worked for me.

Comment: The is option is disabled

Comment: Didn't do the trick here. Sigh. Poking around clueless in AS config.

Comment: There is no Instant Run option for me under Build, Execution, Deployment.

Answer (score 80):

I got this problem too. I fix it by Change `build.gradle` in project

**Change**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

And also I change the `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties(Global Version)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

And got succeed.FYI.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the general lesson here is to first discover which version of the Android build plugin you have :)

Comment: @KennethWorden how to discover that?

Comment: @HomeMade you should be able to check in the Android Studio settings, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Project  (You can change versions and apply from there also)

Answer (score 37):

you need check your gradle version. **gradle -v**

then you should know your gradle version and your gradle plugin version compatible.

Example:

gradle 4.6 is not compatible with gradle plugin 2.2.

so need update **com.android.tools.build:gradle** version to **2.3.3**.

then you need check **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** distributionUrl **gradle version**

google [Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

[image]

**on the other hand**

using newer plugin version might require to update Android Studio

thanks @antek

Comment: I would expand this answer to also note that using newer plugin version might require to update Android Studio

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problems seems to be caused by a mismatch between gradle version, version of com.android.tools.build:gradle (android gradle plugin) and IDE version. Upgrading these versions as close to latest version is best strategy in my experience.

Comment: This is the correct answer. when i use compatible version  as mention in doc it worked like magic.. thanks man

Comment: This was the root of the solution for me. I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260172/how-to-check-the-gradle-version-in-android-studio) useful in actually getting the _Gradle plugin_ updated.

Comment: I've update to Android Studio 4.1.1 and got the same problem, and thankyou.. this is work for me.

Comment: If you use ./gradlew command .Run ./gradlew -v comand rather than gradle -v

Answer (score 22):

I also encountered this error when updating to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

To fix it, I had to add the `google()` repo to both the buildscript and module repositories. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#apply_plugin) here only mentions adding to to the buildscript.

**Project-level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

**App-level build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    ...
    // Documentation doesn't specify this, but it must be added here
    google()
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

had similar problem, issue was different versions of included library. to find out what causes problem run build command with stacktrace

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, i got wifi problem. make sure you have valid internet connection

Comment: Nice catch, I was using offline mode.

Comment: Thanks, was using VPN.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I solved this error only by *Invalidating caches*.

**File > Invalidate caches / Restart**

Answer (score 6):

This is neither an exact answer to the question nor a silver bullet.
However, if nothing works for you e.g. Invalidate cache & restart, Checking build dependency, Disabling Instant Run (I never advise that) etc.

1. Add command-line option `--stacktrace` in **Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler**
2. Now build/assemble gradle once again. You will have detailed information about the cause. e.g. in my case:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException:
>   Could not find com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1Net.

I have misspelled the dependency name in module level gradle file. Hope that help

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably you're using a Gradle version rather than 3.
go to gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change the last line to this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

For those of you working on a team:

I pulled down some changes that included updating the build tools version, but I had not downloaded that new version of the build tools on my machine. Downloading the new version fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 3):

For me, this issue arose due to an incompatible combination of plugin and gradle.

I added these to the code to have it working:

Main build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
```

Main gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the below line in your gradle.build helps.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Usually it depends on Instant run or Gradle, but I tried both variants and nothing helped me. Then I looked through `idea.log` and saw this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A conflict was found between the 
following modules:
 - com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
 - com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
```

I really don't know why this error is not shown in `Gradle Console` or `Event Log` tab. Then I fixed it by adding some code to the end of `android{}` block.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.name == 'support-core-utils') {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'//Or you can use 27.0.1 if it does not conflict with your other dependencies
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because I was using **Charles proxy** on my computer and the **SSL was enabled for all hosts**. And since AS didn't trust my proxy, the network request failed. 
So I had to **disable SSL for all hosts** and **restart my Android Studio**.

Answer (score 2):

With the new google support gradle plugin (`com.google.gms.google-services`) this can be caused by some dependency version problems with your `com.google.android.gms.*` modules.

You can probably see the root cause by running the build command with the `--stacktrace` parameter. i.e.:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies --stacktrace
```

which might output the cause of the problem:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 
>   The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at **[[15.0.2,15.0.2],
>   [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0**. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>               at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$1$_afterResolve_closure1.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:328)
>               at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have changed version of Kotlin plugin in gradle file related to module but hadn't change it in root gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting but as for me help this:

```
 File -> Setting -> Gradle -> disable offline work
```

Answer (score 2):

I have met the similar problem.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0-milestone-1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

> The key is you need to get a way to solve this kind of problems,not to
>   solve this problem.

According to the log above,the most important information is:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Most of the building problems of Gradle will be solved because when you use the specific Gradle build command,you can get more detailed and useful information that are clear.

```
*clean project
./gradlew clean  

*build project
./gradlew build

*build for debug package
./gradlew assembleDebug or ./gradlew aD

*build for release package
./gradlew assembleRelease or ./gradlew aR

*build for release package and install
./gradlew installRelease or ./gradlew iR Release

*build for debug package and install
./gradlew installDebug or ./gradlew iD Debug

*uninstall release package
./gradlew uninstallRelease or ./gradlew uR

*uninstall debug package
./gradlew uninstallDebug or ./gradlew uD 

*all the above command + "--info" or "--debug" or "--scan" or "--stacktrace" can get more detail information.
```

And then I found the problem is related with the version of Gradle,when I have changed Gradle from 5.0 to 4.1,and then it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to specifically stop the `gradlew` and clear caches and this fixed my issues:

```
./gradlew --stop
// Delete all cache files in your project. With git: `git -xfd clean` 
// Delete global cache dir. On Mac it is located in `~/.gradle/caches
```

Found here:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5650#issuecomment-355011135

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue by cleaning all the Gradle cache, stoping the Gradle Daemon process, and created a new build successfully using the following command. Make sure your current directory is android.

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches && ./gradlew --stop && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

I'm using React Native. So I've added following in my scripts in package.json,

```
"build-android": "rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches && cd android && ./gradlew --stop && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd ..",
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the Distribution url at gradle-wrapper.properties

Place it : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

I ignored using **JDK13** with **Android Studio,** So I selected below settings and it was solved:

Step 1. (File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location)

```
Embedded JDK
```

Step 2. (File > Project Structure > Project)

```
gradle plugin 3.6.3 

gradle 5.6.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"`, upgrading it to `27.0.2` fixed the issue.

Also, my android support deps were at version `27.0.2` so they were not aligned to the `buildToolsVersion`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me was to use the system gradle instead of Android Studio's built-in:

SETTINGS -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle

Select *Use local gradle distribution*. To find the path, you can do `which gradle` where the `which` program is supported. It might be `/usr/bin/gradle`.

See also [Error:Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.AndroidSdkHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513651/errorcould-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repositoryv2-androidsdkhandl) for another possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

SETTINGS -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> unselect Offline work
Then sync project, you are good to go.
[image]
If not working , then File > Invalidate caches / Restart - > Invalidate and Restart.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing the target SDK platform installed. I remember this error was straightforward and prompted you to install it automatically. Worth checking that as well.

Answer (score 0):

First Step:File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.
Second step: Press Invalidate/Restart.
done.... Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to do -

**File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files**

[image: Sync Project with Gradle Files]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update **all** the Firebase libraries to the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to change **compile** by **implementation** first, then maybe the problem is your android version, it is not compatible with your code, so update it.

And *Good luck*

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure and confirm that you have the `gradle` folder in you parent project folder, this was my issue it turn out it had been added to `gitignore` and so didn't ship with it.
if you do not have it copy it and add it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have imported the project without gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. Then I added it manually and specified gradle in Project Structure.

Answer (score 0):

For people experiencing this issue after the Nov 5, 2022 RN update 0.71.0-rc.0

changing

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
    }
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2")
    }
```

as well as

```
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

in android/build.gradle fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

add this code into your **gradle.properties** file, It will work well but you may receive other errors.

Answer (score -2):

Just **restart** Android Studio - Usually then everything works again.
(Invalidate Caches + Restart is actually not required).