# Appium java-client caused Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, appium

I'm trying to do test automation using Appium and add java-client in my `app/build.gradle` as dependency. Below here my code:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'

    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5'
    testCompile 'io.appium:java-client:5.0.3'
}
```

Everytime I add `testCompile 'io.appium:java-client5.0.3'` gradle build will failed with the error:

```
Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
```

I've tried follow the workaround in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094037/android-studio-failed-to-notify-project-evaluation-listener-error) but gradle build still failed. Any advise?

Comment: Did https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665772/1746118 also not work?

Comment: @nullpointer yes, I've tried both answers but nothing works for me.