# After updating from Qt 5.11 to 5.12 I start receiving this error at deploying attempt to Android

Tags: android, gradle, deployment, qml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This solution solves the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665772